# How do I use SQLite in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've founde already a few answers to this topic (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037767/create-sqlite-database-in-android)), but it is not working. I only get the warning, that it cannot resolve the method 'openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, null)'.

Here is my sourcecode:

```
public class DBHandler
{
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    DBHandler()
    {
        database = openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the [official examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)?

Comment: Try this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQLite](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) is a opensource SQL database that stores data to a text file on a device. Android comes in with built in SQLite database implementation.

Please check below links

1. [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)
2. [SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)
3. [SQLite and Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

**Structure**

```
 public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
    onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the commenter has given you the example, you will need to create a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and override the `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` methods which will create your database and tables. Then you can use the method `getReadableDatabase( )` or `getWritableDatabase()` of this helper class to get copy of a SQLite database. You can execute the queries on this object.
The code snippet below demonstrates it.

```
public class DBAdapter {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;


    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLES_QUERY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+TABLE_QUERY);
        }
    }

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;

    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, DBNAME, null,DBVERSION);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public Cursor executeQuery() {
        Cursor result = database.rawQuery(YOUR_QUERY, null);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Use [SQLite Open Helper developers guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for more help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Sqlhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "firstname";

Sqlhelper DB = null;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "db";

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "firstname TEXT NOT NULL);";



public Sqlhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.d("DATABASE", "Table Was Created");


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
public void open() {

    getWritableDatabase();
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    onCreate(db);
    Log.d("DATABASE", "Table Was UPDATED");

}
```

Comment: Great, this will definitly help him to understand how SQL Databases in Android work... -1

Answer (score 1):

**Create "database" name package and include it**

**Create SQLitHelper name class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class SQLitHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DataBase_Name = "ABC";
    public static final int Version = 1;
    public static final String TblUser = "TblUser";
    public static final String TblClassList = "TblClassList";
    public static final String TblStudentList = "TblStudentList";

    public SQLitHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DataBase_Name, null, Version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create table " + TblUser +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                "uid INTEGER," +
                "fname TEXT," +
                "lname TEXT," +
                "email TEXT," +
                "password TEXT," +
                "teacher TEXT," +
                "student TEXT," +
                "parent TEXT," +
                "status TEXT," +
                "landing_page TEXT," +
                "createdate TEXT," +
                "birthdate TEXT," +
                "profilepic TEXT," +
                "phone TEXT," +
                "address TEXT," +
                "gender TEXT," +
                "age TEXT," +
                "googleid TEXT," +
                "facebookid TEXT," +
                "alert_time TEXT," +
                "sch_name TEXT,"+
                "login_with TEXT,"+
                "default_zone TEXT)");

        db.execSQL("Create table " + TblClassList +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                "cid INTEGER," +
                "uid INTEGER," +
                "title TEXT," +
                "color TEXT," +
                "startdate TEXT," +
                "enddate TEXT," +
                "qrcode TEXT," +
                "createdate TEXT," +
                "not_submitted_count TEXT," +
                "status TEXT," +
                "extra1 TEXT," +
                "extra2 TEXT)");

        db.execSQL("Create table " + TblStudentList +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                "uid INTEGER," +
                "cid INTEGER," +
                "fname TEXT," +
                "lname TEXT," +
                "email TEXT," +
                "profilepic TEXT," +
                "student_name TEXT," +
                "isleader TEXT," +
                "add_homework TEXT," +
                "track_submission TEXT," +
                "status TEXT," +
                "edit_homework TEXT," +
                "del_homework TEXT," +
                "last_access TEXT)");
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

}
```

**Create DataHelper class**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DataHelper {
    SQLitHelper sqLitHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Context context;
    final String TAG = "DataHelper";

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        sqLitHelper = new SQLitHelper(context);
        this.context = context;
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLitHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


 public void open() {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase = sqLitHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void insertUser(HashMap<String, String> list) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        open();
        try {
            for (String str : list.keySet())
                values.put(str, list.get(str));
            long rowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(SQLitHelper.TblUser, null, values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "insertUser " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    public void updateUser(HashMap<String, String> list, int uid) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        open();
        try {
            for (String str : list.keySet())
                values.put(str, list.get(str));
            long rows = sqLiteDatabase.update(SQLitHelper.TblUser, values, "uid=" + uid, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "insertUser " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    public int getUserRecordCount() {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            open();
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from " + SQLitHelper.TblUser, null);
            count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "userCount : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
        return count;
    }


    public HashMap<String,String> getUserDetail(){
        HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<>();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            open();
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLitHelper.TblUser, null);
            if (cursor.getColumnCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    list.put("uid", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("uid")));
                    list.put("fname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fname")));
                    list.put("lname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lname")));
                    list.put("default_zone", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("default_zone")));
                    list.put("teacher", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("teacher")));
                    list.put("student", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("student")));
                    list.put("parent", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("parent")));
                    list.put("email", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
                    list.put("gender", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gender")));
                    list.put("birthdate", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("birthdate")));
                    list.put("profilepic", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("profilepic")));
                    list.put("sch_name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sch_name")));
                    list.put("login_with", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("login_with")));

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "getUserDetail : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
            if (cursor != null)
                if (!cursor.isClosed())
                    cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public boolean deleteUserList() {
        try {
            open();
            if (sqLiteDatabase.delete(SQLitHelper.TblUser, null, null) > 0){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "deleteUserList : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
        return false;
    }


    public boolean insertClassList(MClassList mClassList) {
        try {
            open();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("cid", mClassList.getId());
            contentValues.put("uid", mClassList.getUid());
            contentValues.put("title", mClassList.getTitle());
            contentValues.put("color", mClassList.getColor());
            contentValues.put("startdate", mClassList.getStartdate());
            contentValues.put("enddate", mClassList.getEnddate());
            contentValues.put("qrcode", mClassList.getQrcode());
            contentValues.put("createdate", mClassList.getCreatedate());
            contentValues.put("status", mClassList.getStatus());
            contentValues.put("not_submitted_count", mClassList.getNot_sub_count());
            long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(SQLitHelper.TblClassList, null, contentValues);
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "insertClassList : Sus");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "insertClassList : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<MClassList> getClassList() {
        ArrayList<MClassList> clssArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            open();
            String Query = QueryBuilder.classListQuery();
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
            if (cursor.getColumnCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    MClassList mClassList = new MClassList();

                    mClassList.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("cid")));
                    mClassList.setUid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("uid")));
                    mClassList.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                    mClassList.setColor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("color")));
                    mClassList.setStartdate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("startdate")));
                    mClassList.setEnddate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("enddate")));
                    mClassList.setQrcode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qrcode")));
                    mClassList.setCreatedate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("createdate")));
                    mClassList.setStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("status")));
                    mClassList.setNot_sub_count(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("not_submitted_count")));

                    clssArrayList.add(mClassList);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "getClassList : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
            if (cursor != null)
                if (!cursor.isClosed())
                    cursor.close();
        }
        return clssArrayList;
    }

    public boolean deleteClassList() {
        try {
            open();
            if (sqLiteDatabase.delete(SQLitHelper.TblClassList, null, null) > 0){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "deleteClassList : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean deleteStudentList() {
        try {
            open();
            if (sqLiteDatabase.delete(SQLitHelper.TblStudentList, null, null) > 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "deleteStudentList : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
        return false;
    }

   public void deleteStudent(int cid,int uid) {
        try {
            open();
            sqLiteDatabase.delete(SQLitHelper.TblStudentList, "uid=" + uid + " AND cid=" + cid, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debugLog(TAG, "deleteStudent : " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

}
```

**Create class QueryBuilder**

```
public class QueryBuilder {

    public static String teacherABCList(int cid) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formatDate = df.format(c.getTime()).toString();

        String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + SQLitHelper.TblTeacherHomeworkAll + " WHERE cid='" + cid + "'" + " AND duedate>= " +"'"+ formatDate+"'" + " ORDER BY duedate DESC ";
        return Query;
    }

==============================

  public static String studentXXXListQuery(int uid,String status) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formatDate = df.format(c.getTime()).toString();


        String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + SQLitHelper.TblStudentHomeworkAll + " WHERE uid='" + uid + "'" + " AND status= " +"'"+ status+"'"+" AND isDone='N'" + " ORDER BY duedate DESC ";
        return Query;
    }

===========================================

 public static String studentListQuery(String questionID) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + SQLitHelper.TblStudentCheckAnswer + " WHERE qid=" + questionID;
        return query;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below example to create database

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
        import android.util.Log;

        import com.ayconsultancy.sumeshmedicals.SumeshMedicalContext;
        import com.ayconsultancy.sumeshmedicals.model.PlaceModel;
        import com.ayconsultancy.sumeshmedicals.utils.Utils;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        /**
         * Created by Admin33 on 16-02-2016.
         */
        public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
            static String DATABASE_NAME = "sumesh_medicals";
            static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            static DBHelper dbHelperInstance;
            static SQLiteDatabase db;

            public DBHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            public static DBHelper getInstance() {
                if (dbHelperInstance == null) {
                    dbHelperInstance = new DBHelper(SumeshMedicalContext.getContext());
                }
                return dbHelperInstance;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                Utils.ShowLogD("in sqlite oncreate");
                try {
                    db.execSQL(DBQueries.CREATE_OTC_TABLE);
                    db.execSQL(DBQueries.CREATE_SHOP_DETAILS_TABLE);
                    db.execSQL(DBQueries.CREATE_USER_DETAILS_TABLE);
                    db.execSQL(DBQueries.CREATE_CITY_TABLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               // insertIntoShopDetails(db);
                //  insertIntoOTcPrescrion(db);

            }

            public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getDababase() {
                if (db == null || (db != null && !db.isOpen())) {
                    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                }
                return db;
            }

            public synchronized void close() {
                super.close();
                if (db != null)
                    db.close();
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to save data into sqlite use following first in main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String one,two;
EditText name,phone;
Button saveButton;
List<StudentModel> list = new ArrayList<StudentModel>();
DatabaseHelper db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    saveButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textName);
    phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textPhone);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            StudentModel student = new StudentModel();
            student.name = name.getText().toString();
            student.phone_number = phone.getText().toString();
            db.addStudentDetail(student);

            list = db.getAllStudentsList();
            print(list);




        }
    });
}
private void print(List<StudentModel> list) {

    String value = "";
    for(StudentModel sm : list){
        value = value+"id: "+sm.id+", name: "+sm.name+" Ph_no: "+sm.phone_number+"\n";
    }

    Log.i("<<<<<<<<<<",value);

}


}
```

then create handler class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Name
public static String DATABASE_NAME = "student_database";


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students";


private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phone_number";

public static String TAG = "tag";



private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENTS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_STUDENTS + "(" + KEY_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT );";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STUDENTS); 

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_TABLE_STUDENTS);

    onCreate(db);
}


public long addStudentDetail(StudentModel student) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Creating content values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, student.name);
    values.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, student.phone_number);

    // insert row in students table

    long insert = db.insert(TABLE_STUDENTS, null, values);

    return insert;
}


public int updateEntry(StudentModel student) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Creating content values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, student.name);
    values.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, student.phone_number);

    return db.update(TABLE_STUDENTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(student.id) });
}


public void deleteEntry(long id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_STUDENTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
}

public StudentModel getStudent(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENTS + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ID + " = " + id;
    Log.d(TAG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    StudentModel students = new StudentModel();
    students.id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
    students.phone_number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONENUMBER));
    students.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));

    return students;
}


public List<StudentModel> getAllStudentsList() {
    List<StudentModel> studentsArrayList = new ArrayList<StudentModel>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENTS;
    Log.d(TAG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            StudentModel students = new StudentModel();
            students.id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
            students.phone_number = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONENUMBER));
            students.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));


            studentsArrayList.add(students);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return studentsArrayList;
}
}
```

then set and get the values

```
public class StudentModel {

public int id;
public String name;
public String phone_number;

public StudentModel(int id, String name, String phone_number) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}
public StudentModel(){

}
}
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code how to use sqlite database

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
            public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

                    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                        super(context, "loginDB.db", null, 1);
                        getWritableDatabase();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
                        String query = "create table registration (id INTEGER,Image BLOB,firstname VARCHAR,Lastname VARCHAR,DateOfBirth VARCHAR,Phone VARCHAR,Gender VARCHAR, Email VARCHAR primary key,Password VARCHAR);";
                        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

                    }
            //method for insert data
            public boolean insertRecord(byte[] imageInByte,String fn) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("Image", imageInByte);
                contentValues.put("Firstname", fn);
                db.insert("signup", null, contentValues);
                return true;
            }

       public boolean updaterecord(String fn,String ln,String unme){
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("Firstname", fn);
                contentValues.put("Lastname", ln);
                contentValues.put("Username", unme);
                return db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "Username = ?", new String[]{(unme)}) > 0;
            }

public boolean deleterecord(String FirstName) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "Firstname = ?", new String[]{FirstName}) > 0;
        }

             public int displayDetail(String email, String password) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from registration where Email='" + email + "'AND Password='" + password + "'", null);

                    return cursor.getCount();
                }

                public ArrayList displayDetails(String email, String password) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from registration where Email='" + email + "'AND Password='" + password + "'", null);

                    ArrayList<ModelClass> arrayList = new ArrayList();
                    ModelClass model;
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                model = new Model();
                                model.setFirstname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Firstname")));
                                model.setLastname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Lastname")));
                                arrayList.add(model);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return arrayList;
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code for SQLite database and basic query.

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context mContext;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DemoDB";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String USER_ID = "id";
    public static final String USER_NAME = "username";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String USER_PASSWORD = "password";

    public static final String CREATE_QUERY_USER_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS
            + " ( "
            + USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + USER_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT"
            + " ) ";

    public SqliteHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY_USER_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
    }

    // Method to openthe Database
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // Method to close the Database
    public void close() {
        if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmailExists(String email) {
        boolean isUserFound = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", new String[]{email.trim()});
        if (cursor != null) {
             if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                 isUserFound = true;
             }
            cursor.close();
        }

         return isUserFound;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USER_NAME, user.userName);
        values.put(USER_EMAIL, user.email);
        values.put(USER_PASSWORD, user.password);

        long todo_id = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
    }

    public boolean login(User user) {
        boolean isLogin = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", new String[]{user.email.trim()});
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(USER_PASSWORD));
                if (pass != null && user.password.equalsIgnoreCase(pass.trim())) {
                    isLogin = true;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return isLogin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)