# Database create in Android

Tags: android

```
 -------This is my Database activity here i m creating database ----------     

     public void Database_Create(){

    try{
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TestExample/Test",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

------ This is my MainActivity ------------------

```
    try{

        Database dbs = new Database();
        dbs.Database_Create();
        Toast.makeText(dbs, "Data Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }   catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I m creating database in Database Activity and i want to call Database_create() method in MainActivity how do i call ?? i m getting an error db object is null , permission already i have given in manifest.xml file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create SQLite database in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037767/create-sqlite-database-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

for first look at this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html),

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DBTest extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
  String TableName = "myTable";

  String Data="";

  /* Create a Database. */
  try {
   myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

   /* Create a Table in the Database. */
   myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
     + TableName
     + " (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 INT(3));");

   /* Insert data to a Table*/
   myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
     + TableName
     + " (Field1, Field2)"
     + " VALUES ('Saranga', 22);");

   /*retrieve data from database */
   Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);

   int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("Field1");
   int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("Field2");

   // Check if our result was valid.
   c.moveToFirst();
   if (c != null) {
    // Loop through all Results
    do {
     String Name = c.getString(Column1);
     int Age = c.getInt(Column2);
     Data =Data +Name+"/"+Age+"\n";
    }while(c.moveToNext());
   }
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText(Data);
   setContentView(tv);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e("Error", "Error", e);
  } finally {
   if (myDB != null)
    myDB.close();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your database like so:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TestExample/Test.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete example for create SQLite database in android sqlite. We need to extend an class with SQLiteOpenHelper. and need to create a constructor to pass parameters from the activity.

```
public class FlightsDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;
    public FlightsDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context,"My_Datas",null,1);
        this.context=context;
    }
```

Then we need to declare the Database name and this have 2-3 options for create database and upgrade the database version when you want some changes in database after publish an app.
Then we will create the table as:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Flight (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,sr TEXT,today_date TEXT,imei TEXT,too TEXT,fromm TEXT,dept_date TEXT,status1 TEXT,file_url TEXT,plane_pic TEXT,plane_name TEXT,idd TEXT)");
    }
```

then you can apply operation for searching , checking data and delete operation over a database.