# How to save the date and time an app has been opened?

Tags: android, datetime

I have an android application and I want that when I open the app(when a user opens the app) to save the date and time the app was opened in a file. I want this to be done automatically, for each opening. I searched for this and found nothing. Do you have any idea for a code that is able to do this?
Please don't tell me to post any code I tried, because I didn't even know where to start. 
I thought about using Calendar and SharedPreferences..maybe?

Thank you! I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Start by breaking down your desired outcome into the simple individual steps (lifecycle of the app--get entry point, get date/time, how to save a file on android devices, what permissions do you need...)

Answer (score 0):

Calendar and shared preferences will work. But more elegant solution will be calendar and SQLite database.
See [Create SQLite database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037767/create-sqlite-database-in-android).
To save date and time everytime you open app, simply put your code in onCreate() method of the main activity.